# Empty trainable variable in keras model(keras version = 2.2.4-tf)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am a beginner in Keras programming.  I just want to manually update the model weights manually in keras so as to get a deep understanding of gradient descent. However, when I tried it, the model either cannot get converged or the loss even gets exploded. My steps are listed as follows:

1. First, I use keras sequential model to fit a quadratic function y = 2*x*x - 7*x + 11
   below is the code using the sequential model:

   ```
   model = Sequential()
   model.add(Dense(64, input_dim = 1, activation = 'relu'))
   model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu'))
   model.add(Dense(1))
   model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
   model.summary()
   ```

   training loss

   [image]

   fitted curved and original one

   [image]
2. Then, I use the following code to update the weight manually:

   ```
   class MyModel(keras.Model):
       def __init__(self):
           super().__init__()
           self.layer1 = Dense(64, input_shape = (1, ))
           self.layer2 = Dense(32)
           self.layer3 = Dense(1)

       def forward(self, x):
           y = keras.activations.relu(self.layer1(x))
           y = keras.activations.relu(self.layer2(y))
           y = self.layer3(y)
           return y

   def loss_fun(y_pred, y):
       return keras_backend.mean(keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y, y_pred))

   def compute_loss(model, x, y, loss_fun = loss_fun):
       logits = model.forward(x)
       mse = loss_fun(y, logits)
       return mse, logits

   def compute_gradients(model, x, y, loss_fun = loss_fun):
       with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
           loss, _ = compute_loss(model, x, y, loss_fun)
       return tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables), loss

   def apply_gradients(optimizer, gradients, variables):
       optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variables))

   def train_batch(x, y, model, optimizer):
       '''
       one step batch training
       '''
       gradients, loss = compute_gradients(model, x, y)
       apply_gradients(optimizer, gradients, model.trainable_variables)
       return loss

   model2 = MyModel()

   epochs = 200
   optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.01) #据查这个0.01是keras默认的learning rate
   loss = []

   x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis = 0)
   y_train = np.expand_dims(y_train, axis = 0)
   for i in range(epochs):   
       l = train_batch(x_train, y_train, model2, optimizer)
       loss.append(l)
       if i % 10 == 0:
           print(f'current loss = {l}')
   ```

   while the loss looks like this:

   [image: loss]
3. I also try another way to manually update the weights:

   ```
   epochs = 200
   lr = 0.01
   optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.01) 
   loss = []

   x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis = 0)
   y_train = np.expand_dims(y_train, axis = 0)
   x_train = tf.cast(x_train, tf.float32)
   y_train = tf.cast(y_train, tf.float32)

   for i in range(epochs):
       y_pred = model5.forward(x_train)
       l = k.mean(keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_train, y_pred))
       gradient = k.gradients(l, model5.trainable_weights)
       new_weights = model5.get_weights() - 0.001 * np.array(gradients)
       model5.set_weights(new_weights)
       if i % 10 == 0:
           loss.append(l)
           print(f'{i}th loss is: {l}')
   ```

   In this case, the loss explodes like this:

   [image: loss]

where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have figure out where the problem is.

When getting the model through the following code:

```
model = MyModel()
```

The trainable variables in model are null.
When I try to print them using this:

```
print(model.trainable_variables)
```

it outputs

```
[]
```

I try to make the weight trainable manually by the following code:

```
for layers in model.layers:
    layers.trainable = True
```

But it still doesn't work at all.